# Prolog algorith with eclipse

Tags: prolog

I use Eclipse with swipl .The code tries to solve this

```
       d o s  
 +     d o s  
 +   t r e s
 = s i e t e
```

generates the output:

```
?- criptograma(L).
L = [[s, 3], [e, 9], [o, 2], [t, 7], [d, 4], [r, 5], [i, 8]]
```

instead of a correct answer

Where am i wrong? :(

Comment: I didn't try to understand your algorithm, but you have a lot of singleton variable warnings. **Never ignore singleton variable warnings.** They tell you that you may have gotten confused about variable names, or forgotten to constrain some variables. For example, why is the last argument of `sum2` a list `[S1, E1, T1]` if `sum2` doesn't talk about `S1` and `E1` at all? Another thing that may be a typo is that in the second clause of `sum` the last argument is `[S1, E1]`, but the order is reversed in the call to `sum1` as `[E1, S1, R2]`, then reversed again in the last argument of `sum2`.

Answer (score 1):

I have some pointingouts.

1.you don't have to define `volteaL` you can just use `reverse`

```
?- reverse([a,b,c],R).
R = [c, b, a].
```

2.you don't have to call `member(R1,L), eliminaElement(R1,L,L2)` just use select/3

```
?- select(Selection,[0,1,2],Rest).
Selection = 0,
Rest = [1, 2] ;
Selection = 1,
Rest = [0, 2] ;
Selection = 2,
Rest = [0, 1] ;
```

3. It seems you overlooked the case sum of three number is over 20.
   `ex:9+8+7=24.` I think this is critical part.

4.This information is redundant, but you can solve this problem much easier with using clpfd(see below).I wrote this code in 2 minuites.

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

solve([D,O,S,T,R,E,I]):-
    [D,O,S,T,R,E,I] ins 0..9,
    all_different([D,O,S,T,R,E,I]),
    100*D + 10*O + S +
    100*D + 10*O + S +
    1000*T + 100*R + 10*E + S #=
    10000*S + 1000*I + 100*E + 10*T + E,
    D #> 0,
    T #> 0,
    S #> 0,
    labeling([ffc],[D,O,S,T,R,E,I]).
```

Test:

```
?- solve([D,O,S,T,R,E,I]).
D = 5,
O = 8,
S = 1,
T = 9,
R = 2,
E = 3,
I = 0 ;
false.
```

Comment: Hi Taku, just to let you know that you don't need to wrap code in HTML tags that add lots of spurious vertical whitespace, it's enough to indent things by four spaces (keyboard shortcut: Ctrl-K) to turn things into a code block. I submitted an edit of your answer.

Comment: Taku Koyahata apologize for the delay. I review your answer and correct the code, but I still do not get the correct result (i already edited it)  :(    

I do not understand well the part of CLP (FD), in the code that you put :(
how could I assign the output of the problem to a variable to avoid placing the list I want to be solved, for example: solve (X): -
instead of:
   solve ([D, O, S, T, R, E, I]): -     ???????

Comment: Can you use trace debbuger (like gtrace in swi)? You can check how your code works one by one with it. you looks beginner, so I recommend not to write whole code at once, but  start developing each small part and check it works correctly ,then go next.

Comment: thank you taku i did that, but i am stuck in this , i dont see the mistake in my code, so if someone can help me correcting the code line where i am wrong ,i could understand cos at this moment my eyes dont see it :(